# Remove "price" from Magento product details page

Tags: magento

I am using tier pricing with a new install of Magento.  I am running into some problems with removing the "price" when using tier price.  When I leave it blank it show $0 and tiered soes not show at all.  When I put a number in, it shows and the tier amounts show.  I sell item in bulk, so I do not want the "price" attribute to show.  How can I hide it?  even if I have to put a price and hide it in the back end, thats fine.  I only want my tiered prices to show on the details page.  Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify or pollute your template, you can use this [extension to hide/remove all kinds of product's price](http://magetools.net/magento-price-remover-hide-price). AND it works for all kind of theme without modify any template or rewrite.

magento connect link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/22443/

Demonstration: http://demo.magetools.net